# Minimum Number of Moves in a Game

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is simple, I have a multiset $S$(where duplicates are allowed) of $N$ numbers.
I play a game wherein I make moves to obtain a multiset $S^{'}$ which has each element occuring atleast twice. The move can either increment or decrement a number of the multiset. What is the minimum number of moves that I need to make?
Consider an example:
$S = \{1,2,3,4\}$
Move 1: Increment 1, $S^{'}=\{1,1,3,4\}$
Move 2: Decrement 4, $S^{'}=\{1,1,3,3\}$
Now each element occurs atleast twice in $S^{'}$. So the min moves needed are 2.

Comment: Game theory assumes at least two players. Where is the second player in your OP?

Comment: Sir, there is no second player. I apologize if I have given the wrong tag. What other tag could have been given?

Comment: I suggest that you state a question (the OP has none) and then let us look for an appropriate tag.

Comment: @mlc But atleast one tag is necessary while I ask a question.

Comment: sure it is; my point is that you have not yet asked a specific question or a problem. What is it that you are interested to find out?

Comment: @mlc As evident from the title as well as example, I am interested in finding the MINIMUM number of moves to achieve the condition mentioned in the OP. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: If you want to have an even number of occurrences for each item, I think it should not be hard to prove that if you sort the list, you just need up to match each number at position 2n+1 with the number at position  2n+2. The problem is that here in some cases you might want to match 2n+1 with 2n.

Comment: @TMM I need occurrence of every item to be atleast twice(not even). Also as it is multiset there can be elements that are already occuring twice or more in it initially. Its obvious that we wont perform any operation on such numbers. Regarding the others, we will either move them to the immediate right or left. This can be solved with DP(dynamic programming).

Comment: The question is: is your "dynamic programming" strategy guaranteed to be optimal? If we have a large set, sorted according to size, I'm not sure it's obvious what should be done with elements somewhere in the middle.